# Is it possible to integrate angular2 with AEM?

Tags: angular, aem, angular2-template

Is it possible to integrate angular2 with AEM enabling the ability of authoring on HTML templates bound to angular2 component. I have seen an example in adobe but it hasn't said anything on authoring.

Comment: what authoring capabilities are you referring to?

Comment: @mickleroy It can be changing the screen label and adding medias

Comment: The authoring framework is not built on Angular2 so extending it with Angular2 is not trivial. You will have to rewrite a lot of code. Also, I don't think this will provide a good RoI as Adobe is extending it's product in a non-Angular way so your compatibility will be strained with each release from Adobe.

Answer (score 1):

From Authoring perspective, Angular 2 (or any SPA) is not ideal. AEM is a CMS which integrated into a lot of other Adobe suites like Campaigns, Target, Assets, Media etc. Authoring experience is designed to leverage the best of these integrations an make content management as easy as possible. This allows a lot of flexibility to the Authors.

SPA on the other hand is more for seamless and versatile UX which is more targeted to the end-user (aka Publisher side of things in AEM). You can design your components to generate Angular compatible/compliant code without changing the authoring experience.

If you want to change the authoring experience to a SPA then you will need to code for all the Adobe's suite integration. I know for sure that Campaign and Target are not easy to get in there and have loads of issues even in 6.3. Angular (in tandem with HTL) causes a lot of issues with preview in target scripts due to sequence of events. Cross browser compatibility for all these complex integrations is also a massive challenge (I gave up on IE which is still a favourite in banks and legals due to whatever reasons).

It can probably be done but the RoI is very questionable and the challenges will require a lot of internal knowledge and digging into AEM's integration with rest of the suite. Also, any upgrades on your AEM instance will flag this as a risk and increase your total cost of ownership.

Answer (score 0):

On my projects:

1) From one side you have Angular which is one page application which use html templates. From other side one of AEM parts is very good WYSIWYG site constructor. So nobody can stop you from create and edit pages in author mode and use them on publish as Angular templates.

2) AEM also is not bad REST server:

- Create/Update/Delete pages from Angular as UGC.
- Control permissions with standard well tested approaches share content via CUG.
- Distribute UGC with AEM mechanics(e.g. reverse replication)

3) Mix linking between AEM pages and Angular routes with `#links` in AEM and direct links in Angular.

**BUT:**

1) It is really difficult to create good rules and follow them when you are mixing AEM and Angular because from the idea they are for different purposes. The same situation you can see with AEM + RDBMS : it is working but way was quite long way and sometimes it was painful.

2) Switching from AEM to Angular is a time. It is fine when all application is Angular(you need to load it once) but if is easy to build your app wrong way when user on each second click has to wait for Angular init.

Comment: But did you say all these keeping in mind that angular2 has been used?

Comment: Yes, we have in production project which fit Angular2 concept very well. 

It was lot of issues with first Angular + AEM (You can find main of them in `BUT` block)

Comment: Do you have any sample implementation or any poc in plunkr or anywhere else?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not share any part of existing code due to NDA.
But I can suggest you to have a look in 2 directions:
1) Page with Angular bootstrap has config which is pointing to "templates" created on by editors.
    1.a) Components on those pages should work in two modes: on author it is standard content on publish it should be content with angular placeholders.
2) For some pages you can create scripts which will render page by selector for angular e.g. `<site>/userprofile.html` will represent profile view for editor but `<site>/userprofile.angularpage.html` is Angular template.

Comment: I can understand what you have described. My only concern is now my angular template is tightly coupled with angular component. The challenge is, to be able to author on that I need to convert it into aem component. At this point I am getting confused how to associate an aem component with an angular2 component.

Comment: There is no connection at all between AEM components and Angular components. This connection you have to introduce by yourself. In our way connection is AEM page <-> Angular component.

Comment: as @AlekseySlyshkov pointed out. It's difficult, I am seeing the same issues as well on a project I'm working on. In theory you can make it work. But in practice it will be on the expense of both authors and developers. If you have routes, its difficult for authors to author those. Also, you cant map angular comps to AEM comps one-to-one unless you use aem comps as ONLY the view (HTML) part of the angular component. Hope this helps.